# Display canvas image from one canvas to another canvas using base64

Tags: html, canvas, base64

E.g. `var new = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

I want the base64 that is present in this new variable to be displayed into 2nd canvas element that is present. But it does not display the base64 image using drawimage method.
It works if I use say `image.png`

Comment: I haven't tried this but you can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript.

Comment: Why don't you want to use drawImage? Why are you using dataURLs?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/copying-a-canvas-element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use base64 to copy the canvas. You can pass the source canvas into the destination canvas' context method, drawImage.

Otherwise you will suffer a serious performance hit. See my jsperf test at http://jsperf.com/copying-a-canvas-element.

`drawImage()` will accept a `Canvas` as well as an `Image` object.

Try this:

```
//grab the context from your destination canvas
var destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');

//call its drawImage() function passing it the source canvas directly
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 3):

1. First create an Image Element & give the Image source as the cached `.DataURL()` source
2. Using the Image `<img />` (which we created earlier) draw the Image Content onto second Canvas element

E.g.:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var ctx1    = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    var ctx2    = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    var src     = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // cache the image data source

    var img     = document.createElement('img'); // create a Image Element
    img.src     = src;   //image source

    ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  // drawing image onto second canvas element
};
```

Comment: This will work but its a bit of a round about way of copying the canvas. Instead of creating a image as a way of copying the data you can simply pass the source canvas to the .drawImage method instead of a temporary image object.

Comment: @RobertHurst please read the question properly .. op mentioned that `I want the base64 that is present in this new variable to be displayed into 2nd canvas element that is present` ..

Comment: Why? If one wants to copy the image to another canvas, they should do it directly. Using base64 data as a method is amazingly slower. http://jsperf.com/copying-a-canvas-element