# How to Copy Contents of One Canvas to Another Canvas Locally

Tags: html, canvas

I'd like to copy ALL contents of one canvas and transfer them to another all on the client-side. I would think that I would use the `canvas.toDataURL()` and `context.drawImage()` method to implement this but I am running into a few issues.

My solution would be to get `Canvas.toDataURL()` and store this in an Image object in Javascript, and then use the `context.drawImage()` method to place it back.

However, I believe the `toDataURL` method returns a 64 bit encoded tag with `"data:image/png;base64,"` prepended to it. This does not seem to be a valid tag, (I could always use some RegEx to remove this), but is that 64 bit encoded string AFTER the `"data:image/png;base64,"` substring a valid image? Can I say `image.src=iVBORw...ASASDAS`, and draw this back on the canvas?

I've looked at some related issues:
[Display canvas image from one canvas to another canvas using base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137372/display-canvas-image-from-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-using-base64)

But the solutions don't appear to be correct.

Answer (score 344, accepted):

Actually you don't have to create an image at all. `drawImage()` will accept a `Canvas` as well as an `Image` object.

```js
//grab the context from your destination canvas
var destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
//call its drawImage() function passing it the source canvas directly
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```

Way faster than using an `ImageData` object or `Image` element.

Note that `sourceCanvas` can be a [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement), or a [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement). As mentioned by [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180785/dave) in a comment below this answer, you **cannot use a canvas drawing context as your source**. If you have a canvas drawing context instead of the canvas element it was created from, there is a reference to the original canvas element on the context under `context.canvas`.

Here is a jsPerf to demonstrate why this is the only right way to clone a canvas: http://jsperf.com/copying-a-canvas-element

Comment: a small point which tripped me up: while you can draw a canvas (`HTMLCanvasElement`), you *cannot* draw a context (`CanvasRenderingContext2D`). Use `myContext.canvas` instead.

Comment: @Dave comment is a **MUST READ**... woud give +10 if possible ;). @Robert-Hurst must complement his answer with this comment since he doesn't specify from where `source canvas` comes from...

Comment: Could you please provide an example ?

Comment: @RogerGajraj Actually the canvas does not have to be visible. This is demonstrated there => https://jsfiddle.net/d36wwtvj

Answer (score 9):

@robert-hurst has a cleaner approach.

However, this solution may also be used, in places when you actually want to have a copy of Data Url after copying. For example, when you are building a website that uses lots of image/canvas operations.

```
    // select canvas elements
    var sourceCanvas = document.getElementById("some-unique-id");
    var destCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName("some-class-selector")[0];

    //copy canvas by DataUrl
    var sourceImageData = sourceCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var destCanvasContext = destCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var destinationImage = new Image;
    destinationImage.onload = function(){
      destCanvasContext.drawImage(destinationImage,0,0);
    };
    destinationImage.src = sourceImageData;
```

Comment: I was needing to copy the contents of a canvas to use elsewhere - this was perfect as it generated ~80KB of data vs ~60MB using `getImageData`