# How to change content of two div - canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two div's :

```
<div id="div_h">
    <canvas class="canvas" width="570" height="428" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>


<div  id="div_p">
    <canvas class="canvas" width="828" height="528" id="canvas"  ></canvas>
</div>
```

I have a button that change the content of these div's:

```
$('#finish').click(function() {

                $el_div_h = $('#div_h');
                $el_div_p = $('#div_p');

                $div_h      = $el_div_h.html();
                $div_p  = $el_div_p.html();

                $el_div_h.empty();
                $el_div_p.empty();

                $el_div_h.html($div_p);
                $el_div_p.html($div_h);

            });
```

but when I click on finish button, canvas changed to white color.
content of my canvas is two different images.

Comment: So, you want to swap the canvases from div_p to div_h and vice versa?

Comment: yes.I want to swap two canvas.

Comment: you'll need to rerun the code for instantiating whatever is in the canvas. the canvas elements will be completely new dom elements after this.

Comment: just swapping the position of the divs using CSS would be a much easier and more performant solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242006/html5-copy-a-canvas-to-image-and-back what about drawing the content of one canvas to another? (you may need a hidden-dummy canvas to shuffle the images around)

Comment: This is duplicate question. Similar question is already there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278913/swapping-div-with-canvas-elements-using-javascript Please verify before posting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
$('#finish').click(function() {
    var elms1 = $('#div_h').children().detach();
    var elms2 = $('#div_p').children().detach();
    $('#div_h').append(elms2);
    $('#div_p').append(elms1);
    console.log($('#div_h').find("canvas").attr("id"));
    console.log($('#div_p').find("canvas").attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="finish">FINISH</button>
<div id="div_h">
    <canvas class="canvas" width="570" height="428" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div  id="div_p">
    <canvas class="canvas" width="828" height="528" id="canvas"  ></canvas>
</div>
```

This will keep the `<canvas>`es intact because you're not storing the `<div>`s' HTML code, you're storing the child elements of those containers.