# Does an offscreen canvas have as much "space" as a normal one?

Tags: html, canvas, coffeescript, off-screen

I have a situation similar to [this question about copying data between canvases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405336/how-to-copy-contents-of-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-locally), but in my case I think I'm running into issues with the canvas engine itself and I'd like some understanding/guidance on what I might be doing wrong.

I'm creating an offscreen canvas with the same width and height as the onscreen canvas.

```
  @offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')

  # assign same dimensions as onscreen canvas
  @offscreenCanvas.width  = canvas.width
  @offscreenCanvas.height = canvas.height
```

Then I'm drawing from the offscreen canvas to the onscreen one like this:

```
# grab the width and height of the canvas
{ width, height } = @canvasElement
{ x, y } = offset

# copy image from layer into canvas
@context.drawImage 
  @offscreenContext.canvas, -x, -y, width, height, -x, -y, width, height
```

The offset is also the argument into a function which translates the "live" canvas context before all this drawing takes place.

```
@context.save()
@context.translate(@offset.x,@offset.y)
@renderer.draw(world, @offset)
@context.restore()
```

In other words we're trying to grab the section of the offscreen context that corresponds to the translated offset of the on-screen context.

This has some issues. When the offset moves the 'camera' far from the origin, you encounter the 'edges' of the offscreen canvas.

[image: visual indication of the problem with the edge of the offscreen canvas]

Note that when I do the same rendering operations against the onscreen canvas, the elements are fine.

It seems like the offscreen canvas isn't quite as good about handling drawing off its "edges" the same way the canvas is (silently ignores drawing commands outside of its defined region.) In other words, the offscreen canvas doesn't seem to reflect any drawing I've done above or to the left of `[0,0]` (or alternatively, below or to the right of `[width,height]`.) Are there ways of accommodating this?

---

Things I've tried:

- adjusting up the width and height of the offscreen canvas (this unfortunately seems to have a hard-to-predict impact on coordinates)

Comment: Oops! I accidentally deleted my comment while trying to edit it. An in-memory canvas should behave the same as one visible in the window. How far are you offsetting to accommodate the camera position?

Comment: @markE I can see the issue even with a small offset, like (-5, -5) or (5,5). Note I'm setting up the offscreen canvas to have the same width and height as the onscreen one.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to address the issue by indicating a **larger offscreen canvas size.** The issue with coordinates seemed to be about Isomer's origin position (which you can override by passing in a different origin.)

A minor note: as per [MDN's article on canvas optimization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas) you need to ensure the coordinates and dimensions you pass to `drawImage` aren't floating point (i.e, call `Math.floor` on them.) I was running into odd antialiasing artifacts without this.