# ant't 'putImageData' with 'imagedata' from other canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata, putimagedata

I have two canvases on the same page, with different ids. I use the first canvas to draw Images and the second is like an album where you can see all of your paintings...... When I use `var Img = painter.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100)` and `album.putImageData(Img, 0, 0)` it doesn't work. Plz help!

Code : (there may be some errors, because this is hand written write now, my original code is too long)

HTML :

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="album" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
<canvas id="painter" width="100" height="100" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>
<button onclick="sub()">Submit to album</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
var album = document.getElementById("ambum").getContext("2d");
var painter = document.getElementById("painter").getContext("2d");
var SRC = "";

function draw(evt) {
  var X = evt.clientX;
  var Y = evt.clientY;
  painter.beginpath();
  painter.fillStyle = "red";
  painter.fillRect(X - 1000, Y, 100, 100);
}
function sub() {
  var SRC = painter.getImageData(1000, 0, 100, 100);
  album.beginPath();
  album.putImageData(SRC, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Give us some more code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Copy Contents of One Canvas to Another Canvas Locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405336/how-to-copy-contents-of-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-locally).

Comment: No, that's one canvas to the same canvas, this is one canvas to another canvas!

Comment: You are trying to get the imageData out of the canvas' coordinates : your canvas is `1000` px wide and you are getting the pixels from coordinates 1000,0 to 1100,100. You'll get only transparent pixels, so nothing to put on the second canvas. Also, do you know you can `drawImage(HTMLCanvasElement, x, y)` ?

Comment: please create reproducible example

Comment: Kaiido put as answer and I will tick it!

Comment: I prefer you to delete the question since it is unlikely to help any future reader.

Comment: I have got an answer so ok. ; )

Comment: how do we delete a post?

Comment: Sorry missed that last comment. You just have to click the [delete] link under your post