# Rendering problems when saving multiple Dygraphs as a PNG on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, export, png, responsive, dygraphs

I have a web application that uses Dygraphs to create charts.

The application allows a user to create multiple Dygraph charts (each with their own Y-Axis) that will be stacked on top of each other.

Here's an example of what the multiple Dygraphs look like on a PC browser: Notice that the example displays three different Dygraphs each having their own Y-axis, but the X-axis is hidden for the top 2 charts and visible on the bottom chart.[image]

I will allow the user to save the chart to disk as a PNG. - The way I currently save the multiple Dygraphs as one PNG is:

1. Create a target canvas that will be used to contain all the visible Dygraphs
2. Extract each canvas out of each Dygraph, then add each canvas to the target canvas **
3. Create a PNG via the .toDataURL() function on the target canvas

Here's an example of what the above screenshot looks like when saved as one PNG: (This is exactly what I want from the PNG)
[image]

The procedure works fine on browsers on a PC. But when I attempt to save the multiple Dygraphs into one PNG on a phone/tablet browser, the resultant PNG doesn't match the graph that is visible on the screen.

Example: 
Here's what the multiple Dygraphs look like on an iPad (screenshot)
[image]

And here's what the resultant PNG looks like (Notice how the width and height of each chart does not match the actual iPad display).
[image]

I don't understand why the PNG is rendered correctly when I use a PC browser, but is not rendered correctly when I use a browser on a mobile device.

I'm not sure if this problem is due to limitations of the Canvas.toDataURL() function or if this is a Dygraphs problem or something else. I'm fishing for advice that may point me in the right direction and/or shed light on this particular problem.

**I should mention that I use [Juan Manuel Caicedo Carvajal's Dygraph-Export extension](http://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround/hack for the problem stated in my OP was to make a change to the Dygraph source in the `Dygraph.getContextPixelRatio` function.

Notice in the code below that I set `devicePixelRatio = 1`

**dygraph-combined.js**

```
Dygraph.getContextPixelRatio = function (context) {
try {
    //var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    var devicePixelRatio = 1; // Hack!!!  
    var backingStoreRatio = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;
    if (devicePixelRatio !== undefined) {
        return devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio;
    } else {
        // At least devicePixelRatio must be defined for this ratio to make sense.
        // We default backingStoreRatio to 1: this does not exist on some browsers
        // (i.e. desktop Chrome).
        return 1;
    }
} catch (e) {
    return 1;
}
};
```

In my case, this hack fixed my problem (stated in the OP) and didn't negatively affect any other parts of my application that uses `Dygraphs`. That said, if you find a better/correct way to fix the problem stated in the OP, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the Problem occurs, because the generated canvas isn't rendered fully to the responsive screen of an iPad.

You can try to export the original canvas (instead of generating a new one with the said library) yourself with toDataUrl https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Dygraphs generates 2 canvas, one for the legend and one for the actual graph and lays them ontop of each other. So make sure you choose the right one (not the _hidden_canvas). If the examples works you can draw the legend onto the graph canvas with canvas.drawImage(otherCanvas) 
[How to Copy Contents of One Canvas to Another Canvas Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405336/how-to-copy-contents-of-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-locally)

Hope this helps. Keep me updated!