# How to copy canvas element from a page with all its properties?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, google-chrome-devtools

I found a canvas generator website. I would like to copy the canvas to my local environment for experimental purposes.

Is there a way to inspect it in chrome and export its drawn content only?

Comment: Question duplicate, please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141590/4050578

Comment: Thanks! But how do I actually use this technique? I mean I can copy the canvas to the same page by creating another canvas on it... But how do I export it so I can use it in a completely new file and environment?

Comment: Can't copy the canvas context from console :( So I have no idea how to "export" it

Comment: You can't "export" a canvas's state as markup. You have to export it as an image, and then load the image onto the canvas in your local file.

Comment: So whats the point of using the image in a canvas instead of simply as an image? The edit-ability and stuff?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to inspect it in chrome and export its drawn content only?

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can take [screenshots of specific HTML nodes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#node-screenshots) in DevTools, including canvas elements.

Try it out at my [take a screenshot of a canvas demo](https://canvas-screenshot.glitch.me/).

1. press cmd+opt+c or ctrl+shift+c to open the elements panel
2. [select the canvas element](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#select)
3. press cmd+shift+p or ctrl+shift+p to open the command menu
4. start typing `screenshot` and select `capture node screenshot`

[image: canvas screenshot demo]

Comment: I think they want to copy the canvas element and the associated scripts (not a png)

Answer (score -1):

Canvases are graphics that is the result of a javascript code. These results can be exported as gif/jpg/png.

> The HTML  element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript.
>
> The  element is only a container for graphics. You must use JavaScript to actually draw the graphics.
>
> Canvas has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and adding images. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp)

So to have that as RenderingContext that is the return value of canvas.getContext() you must have the javascript that generated it.

An alternative would be to export the canvas result as gif/jpg/png.

Comment: Perhaps you should [cite your source](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_intro.asp).

Comment: AFAIK only Safari supports exporting to gif and pdf.