# Can a js function calling several html canvas draw and drawImage methods be saved into a single Image object?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can a js function calling several html canvas draw and drawImage methods be saved into a single Image object?

Been searching for a way to do this. I was thinking about utilizing the html canvas clip() method somehow, but no luck as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert an in-memory canvas [to a blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), and then load it into the `Image` via [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static).

But depending on your end goal, you might not even need an `Image` object, for example: [you can draw a canvas directly on another canvas' rendering context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141590/5108418) without needing an intermediary image.

```js
document.getElementById("btndraw").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    const img = await drawToNewImage(drawToContext);
    document.getElementById("divtarget")
      .appendChild(img);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});

async function drawToNewImage(drawFn) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = 100;
  canvas.height = 100;
  
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  drawFn(ctx);
  const blob = await new Promise(resolve => {
    canvas.toBlob(resolve);
  });
  const img = new Image(100, 100);
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return img;
}

function drawToContext(ctx) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btndraw">Draw</button>
<div id="divtarget"></div>
```