# putImageData same as drawImage

Tags: html, drawimage, putimagedata

As Im drawing multiple objects in the same context layer I have stumbled across something.

```
 context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
```

This will overwrite everything in the area of this image data. Dose not mater if data is transparent of not.

Unlike when you draw it to the context.

```
context.drawImage(spriteImage, x, y);
```

If it is drawn transparent areas of the image will still act just as they are set, transparent.

So my question is is there a way to `drawImage` of "ImageData" that is used in `putImageData`?

I guess an easy solution for this would be another context layer, but that no good for this, as I have a few sprite types that have to share the same layer to be rendered properly and not look bad when it comes to the feel of x, y and z aspects.

Comment: Would offscreen rendering be viable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is putImageData(...) more performant than drawImage(...)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721898/is-putimagedata-more-performant-than-drawimage)