# In cocoonjs Which one of these methods give most performance for canvas

Tags: android, html, canvas, cocoonjs

Goal is to redraw sprites so i can have sprite animations...

there are 3 methods of doing it:

- Draw directly from image (using drawImage function)
- Draw once on canvas then draw directly from there using drawImage.
- Draw once on canvas, load it in image data, and then draw it from imageData object using putImageData.

I wanted to know which one of these methods are better suited for cocoonjs.

I have seen benchmarks and there is no conclusive answer for me. Maybe you can see something that i can't.

http://jsperf.com/canvas-drawimage-vs-putimagedata/3

According to benchmarks, chrome does better with drawImage on Desktop whereas Android native browser do better with putimage. Cocoonjs being accelerated canvas i have no way of even guessing. So anyone from cocoonjs or someone who is familiar could help her then please do so.

Common sense would say putImage should be fastest but that's not always the case.

[Is putImageData(...) more performant than drawImage(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721898/is-putimagedata-more-performant-than-drawimage)

but again cocoonjs being browser running in mobile with accelerated canvas none of these may apply.

Comment: did you ever findout?

Comment: no but common way was load from canvas..