# Is it possible to set background image in canvas HTML5 and can do some paint functionality like Undo,Erase,Clear,Save that background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to know about canvas HTML5.
In my base canvas element i want to set background image,and on that i want to perform some functionality like in paint Erase,Undo,Clear and save that effected image(after applying all the effect undo,clear)..
Any suggestion or example..

Comment: Duplicate of [Save/restore background area of HTML5 Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858187/save-restore-background-area-of-html5-canvas) and/or [Clear Canvas Rect but Keep Backgrond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596434/clear-canvas-rect-but-keep-background).

Answer (score 4):

You can draw the Background to the canvas, by using drawImage(). All further Manipulations are painted ontop the Image.

When you hav finished your work you can Export your Canvasstate to an Image.

But you have to Hold a History for all task, because the canvas will be directly modified.

May be the Save and restore Method are helpful.

It is important, that you draw your image to the canvas first, so all other effects will affect the image.

Comment: After doing undo,clear,draw(with pencil n color),when i save that image,i am not getting that effected image , i got saved image default white background and some drawn on that canvas by me.But in actual suppose i set in canvas the  'backgroundImage':'url(./tmp/Koala.jpg)' ..i want this as saved image with all effect i did(undo,draw,clear)..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and best perfomance practise would be to put that background as a div behind the canvas.

Comment: But how can you tell me in a practical way...?

Answer (score 0):

The [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) can be used for undo and redo.

The [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) method of the Canvas object can be used to save an image.