# How to set the background image to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, background, html5-canvas, webgl

Well, I want set a `background-image` depth, instead of that degraded background. I tried a lot of things, i tried a lot of answers from this community, and no way... the result is ever with the `background-image` not visible or above the particles. I just want that the `background-image` replaces the current `background-color`.

I wish that anyone be able to help me with correct code, thanks and sorry for my English.

https://codepen.io/at80/pen/tqdmv

```
<canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want debugging help you must create a a [minimum verifiable complete example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example) and put it **in the question itself**. Just posting a link to your code is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be able to fully answer your question, as there is a lot of shader code to look through.

What you need to do is make sure that when a fragment draws something that is not a leaf (e.g. the background), it has an alpha value of `0.0`. The easiest would be to have `gl_FragColor.a = 0.0;` somewhere. I'm new to OpenGL/WebGL so I can't help you by finding the exact locations or methods of doing it.

You have quite a lot of fragment shaders and they are each doing different things. The shader `<script id="bg_fsh" type="x-shader/x_fragment">` controls just the background, but it is not enough on its own.

Once you have managed to make the background transparent in the fragment shaders, you can set a background image somehow, such as on a `<div>` containing the canvas and it should show through.

Comment: yeah i did that  but i only achieved turn black the background, in my code i have it.

Comment: @Menzezzz you can probably use a CSS blending mode (mix-blend-mode/background-blend-mode) with the DOM element itself such as "screen" to mix your final image with the black color. But webgl + blending can be somewhat costly performance wise.

Comment: i do it!!! just i tried before of change gl_FragColor.a value, but all screens turns black... without flowers but i think becuse when i changed it didnt had background-image. Rigth now after trying a lot of things i tryed again and i remember this atribute thanks to you. And just when i thought now or i left it, i chaneg this value and works!! ty

Answer (score -2):

You can not set background image of canvas image directly.  This link of stackoverflow.com will describe more about possibility to set background image 
[Is it possible to set background image in canvas HTML5 and can do some paint functionality like Undo,Erase,Clear,Save that background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367221/is-it-possible-to-set-background-image-in-canvas-html5-and-can-do-some-paint-fun)