# Change background image in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to change background image in HTML5 canvas.

I want to use 2 different thumbnails as buttons and when I click on one of the images the background should be change to that particular image.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://flowplayer.org/demos/skinning/canvas-background.html).

Comment: Strongly related (but not exact dups): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5600671/405017 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858187/save-restore-background-area-of-html5-canvas

Answer (score 0):

#### Technique 1

1. On `click` of the appropriate buttons set a unique CSS class on your `<canvas>` element.
2. Use CSS to apply a background image to your canvas.

Drawing commands and erasing your canvas will not affect the CSS-applied background image behind your content.

#### Technique 2

1. Write a `redraw()` function that knows how to erase the canvas and regenerate your drawing, including determining what image to draw as the background first.
2. On `click` of the buttons set a variable and re-invoke your `redraw()` function. It will erase your canvas and use the variable to draw the correct image.