# Possible to deep clone HTML5 canvas element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

We saw this SO post on cloning HTML5 canvas elements: [Any way to clone HTML5 canvas element with its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content)

We tried doing a deep clone with jQuery (i.e., $(canvas).clone(true) ), but the image data didn't seem to copy over.

Is this not possible with jQuery?

Comment: `$(canvas).clone(true, true))`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Thanks, though.

Comment: Probably a daft question but you are inserting the clone back into the DOM, aren't you?

Comment: Possible solution: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/content-retention-when-cloning-html5-canvas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need to copy any attached event handlers (which, in general, I doubt is possible), I'd just use the currently accepted solution to [Display canvas image from one canvas to another canvas using base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137372/display-canvas-image-from-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-using-base64)

```
//grab the context from your destination canvas
var destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');

//call its drawImage() function passing it the source canvas directly
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```

Of course, you'd have to create the destination canvas first, so, before that, you'd have to:

```
var destinationCanvas    = document.createElement('canvas');
destinationCanvas.width  = sourceCanvas.width;
destinationCanvas.height = sourceCanvas.height;
```

Comment: This is what we wound up doing.