# Drawing in canvas from base 64 image as source

Tags: html5-canvas, base64, onload

I'm using cropping plugin from http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html to select an image area. When working with a common URL src image, the cropping preview works. When the src is a base 64 string, it doesn't.
Been Googling about possible reasons, but no luck.
Code looks like this:

```
function updatePreview(c) 
{
    if(parseInt(c.w) > 0) 
    {
        var img = new Image,
        src = $('.jcrop-holder img').attr('src'),
        cvs = document.getElementById('preview'),
        ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onload = function() 
        {
            console.log('Onload event fired!');
            var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h, 0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);    
            var dataURL = cvs.toDataURL();
            new_image = dataURL;    
        }
        img.src = src;
        if ( img.complete || img.complete === undefined ) 
        {
            console.log('Undefined!');
            img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
            img.src = src;
        }

    }
};
```

Also, when I start dragging the area selector, with the code64 image it suffers from certain delay.

Answer (score 1):

The base 64 I have comes from another canvas, I have found here: [Display canvas image from one canvas to another canvas using base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137372/display-canvas-image-from-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-using-base64) that the best option is to use the originary canvas as source for the drawimage(). The problem is still the performance, but I will write another question more specific.